# Estimation methods for temperature evolution of a high $\Delta H_{mix}$ dilution ($\ce{KOH}$ in water)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, thermodynamics, aqueous-solution, enthalpy, mixtures

**Question up front:** Can temperature evolution in solutions be short-hand-estimated by simple state based calculations - with reasonable expectations of precision? (+/- 10° C)

I am trying to calculate the added hassle of ordering some 15 metric tonnes of potassium hydroxide at high concentration, so as to have a shorter lead time, less transportation and - surprisingly enough - pay less per unit of active ingredient. I can arrange slow dilution in a suitable tank, but I'd like to estimate the worst case scenario. We will be mixing $1$ m$^3$ potassium hydroxide into $12$ m$^3$ cold demineralized water, and then after a temperature reset repeat that 9-10 times with decreasing difference of concentration for each - I assume the first will be the worst. The enthalpy of mixing is worryingly large at  $-57$ $\frac{kJ}{mol}$ the need for double checking any estimation of the temperature evolution is acute.

I know there exists a complicated way of calculating a caloric estimation; if this was in a previous situation where I had access to such, I would have cheated and used the thermodynamic software. However I was wondering about the precision of doing a simple state based comparison.

- state 1: given mass of $\ce{KOH}$ in a 46% concentration
- state 2: given mass of $\ce{KOH}$ in a 25% concentration plus added water.

I believe I have available the $C_p$'s of the different concentrations.

$$C_{p,T1} \times m_{tot} \times T_1 \simeq C_{p,T2} \times m_{tot} \times T_2 + H_{i} \times m_{\ce{H2O,} added} + H_{mix} \times m_{\ce{KOH}}$$

With a known T1 this can then be solved for T2.

IIRC, I am now ignoring change in enthalpy based on temperature (small error). I believe I am also overforecasting due to the fact that I am not diluting to infinity, but stopping at 25%. I might also be slightly rusty in thermodynamics so my napkin-equation there might also be all wrong of course.